# selecting with nested conditions in 3 table joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

following is db fiddle for tables and query.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wcgBNqmhcfeKREAo3XyvtZ/3

META

[image: meta table]

POSTS

[image: posts table]

TERMS_RELATIONSHIP

[image: terms_relationship table]

i want to select post ID from posts based on meta data it has and terms connection it has
but somehow it is behaving abruptly,
as when i pass

```
AND(tr.term_id = 1 or tr.term_id = 2)

.....
HAVING ....OR CONDITIONS ... AND (sum(tr.term_id in (1,2)) = 2)
```

it works fine but when i pass

```
AND(tr.term_id = 3 or tr.term_id = 4)

.....
HAVING ....OR CONDITIONS ... AND (sum(tr.term_id in (3,4)) = 2)
```

it doesn't work and return no rows.
i want to check if both term_id exists for a given post AND either of the meta condition set exists.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM posts p
JOIN meta m ON p.id = m.object_id
JOIN terms_relationship tr ON p.id = tr.object_id
WHERE
m.object_name='post' and tr.relationship_type = 'post-term'
    
-- META QUERY;
    
AND(
(m.meta_key = 'location' and m.meta_value = 'new city')
or (m.meta_key = 'price' and m.meta_value = 100)
or (m.meta_key = 'color' and m.meta_value = 'red')
)
OR(
(m.meta_key = 'location' and m.meta_value = 'delhi')
or (m.meta_key = 'price' and m.meta_value = 100))
    
-- TERM QUERY;
    
AND(
tr.term_id = 1 or tr.term_id = 2
)
    
GROUP BY p.id
    
having (sum( meta_key in ('location', 'price', 'color')) = 3
OR sum( meta_key in ('post_type', 'location')) = 2)
AND (sum(tr.term_id in (1,2)) = 2)
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff may be you can save me

Comment: what are you trying to do ? explain the logic in plain english

Comment: @eshirvana , i want to select post ID from posts based on meta data it has and terms connection it has, i want to check if multiple term_id exists for a given post AND either of the given meta data condition exists.

Comment: @Pepper may be u can help me here ?

Comment: think your query is giving duplicates because of the conditions related to meta. And why this should be (sum(tr.term_id in (3,4)) = 2) ?   shouldnt you use count(term_id) to check if both terms are present?

Comment: Removed the having clause and added two distinct count of meta id and term id in the select [fiddle] (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5meRGRG8WMphPzMhcCXK98/0)  you can use this as temp and write a query on top to get the post ids.